# Express node ejs link issues

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make a button go to another page which I felt like I knew what I was doing but obviously I am over looking something here.

## navbar.ejs (partial)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-defaulr">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Migrant Med</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/add_client.ejs">Sign-ip</a></li>
                <li><a href="registerd.ejs">registered</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<hr>
```

## server.js

// Registered route

```
app.get('/registered', (req, res) => {
    Client.find({}, (err, clients) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('registered', {
                title: 'Migrant Med | Registry',
                header: 'Registered Clients',
                clients: clients
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Am I missing something in the linking of the path? Or in the href itself I have tried so many combinations

Answer (score 0):

The route handler "listens" for requests to `/registered`:

```
app.get('/registered', ...)
```

So the link should point to that exact path:

```
<li><a href="/registered">registered</a></li>
```

Comment: says cannot GET /registered.ejs i've tried it your way numerous times thinking man this should be working

`<li><a href="/registerd.ejs">registered</a></li>`

Comment: Ahh apologies your talking about removing the .ejs yes I have done that as well and even in reading it I removed it just now and it says the same thing minu the .ejs on it